# How can I run Ubuntu and macOS side by side?

Tags: virtualization, mac, macosx

I have a (new to me) 2014 MacBook Air running macOS big sur.  I installed Ubuntu 20.04 and rEFind.

It has been months and I always just use Ubuntu because I love it, I have customized it to my liking and I'm very comfortable with it's shortcuts etc.

I never had an apple computer before so I am quite unfamiliar with macOS.

What I want to do is learn and use the macOS system but I want to have Ubuntu right there by my side so I can comfortably do what I have to do while slowly getting comfortable with macOS.  In other words run Ubuntu inside macOS.

I have never used any emulators or virtual machines but I saw some people mention "parallels" but I would prefer something that is free.

Would it be possible to run a clone of my ubuntu system side by side? Or would a fresh install be necessary?

What would be the most practical, user friendly and well documented way to achieve what I am looking for?

Thanks

Comment: You can certainly do this by converting your existing Ubuntu installation into a VirtualBox image and running it as a VM inside MacOS, but you may want a second machine nearby during the process to test the virtual disk was correctly created before wiping the MacBook for a new OS installation 